# setState() called after dispose()

Tags: flutter

im trying to authenticate users using flutter and firebase. Once a user creates his account, he's redirected to the email verification screen where he should follow the link sent to his email. After that, his name will be displayed on the home screen after verification.

The problem is that i'm always getting the following error: setState() called after dispose() whenever I try to get his firstname and lastname from the cloud firestore.

Here is my code:

```
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
  String? firstname;
  String? lastname;

  void getData() {
    FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('users')
        .doc(user!.uid)
        .snapshots()
        .listen((data) {
      setState(() {
        firstname = data.data()!['nom'];
        lastname = data.data()!['prenom'];
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    getData();

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 12.0),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [Text('Hello,', style: GoogleFonts.lato())],
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 10,
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 12),
            child: Text('${firstname} ${lastname}'.toUpperCase(),
                style: GoogleFonts.lato(
                    fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
          )]));
```

I tried several solutions found on the net but couldn't solve the problem, the only solution that worked for me was delaying the timer for the email verification.
Can anyone help me out with the issue? thanks in advance!

Comment: You can store the `StreamSubscription` reference obtained from calling `.listen` on snapshots, and then in your dispose, you can call, `subscription.cancel()`.

Comment: Tried using the boolean  mounted and it worked as I have firstly thought that it's a specific variable declared by the owner of that thread. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check boolean property `mounted`

````
if (this.mounted) {
  setState(() {
    // Your state change code goes here
  });
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

Try

```dart
 @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getData();
  }
```

and remove the setState in getData. Assign the values directly to the variable

Comment: already updated the answer since I oversaw the 1st issue. You cannot set the state before the build override. initState has to be in "my" order

Comment: That's not really the problem here. We keep listening to stream even after the widget disposed and that's why getting this error. Cancelling the subscription in dispose should be the right answer.

Comment: Tried the first solution and still getting the same error, I'll try cancelling the subscription in dispose now as suggested in the second solution.

Comment: @Ryosuke: You might be right. Typically not disposing the listener just creates a memory leak. But with setState you are probably right that this throws an exception. I am preferring to separate all this logic from the view